# Access second back camera on iphone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I would like to capture images using the secondary back camera on the iphone 7.  How do I force the back camera to use the second lens to take images? When I print out the available devices there was only 1 back camera.

```
Availible devices: Optional([<AVCaptureFigVideoDevice: 0x105e12f70 [Back Camera][com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:0]>, <AVCaptureFigVideoDevice: 0x105d281e0 [Front Camera][com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:1]>, <AVCaptureFigAudioDevice: 0x174097c00 [iPhone Microphone][com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_audio:0]>])
```

Picture to show what I'm talking about..
[image]

Comment: Which camera are you trying to use DuoCamera or WideAngleCamera?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by those but I'm trying to use the camera that is zoomed in the  f2.8 "telephoto" lens?

Comment: `if let builtInTelephotoCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInTelephotoCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back) { }`

Comment: do you still need help accessing it ?

Comment: @LeoDabus Will this solely use the 1 lens?  And thanks I will look into it.

Comment: declare `var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?` before the conditional  and set `defaultVideoDevice =  builtInTelephotoCamera` inside the conditional

Comment: then `let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: defaultVideoDevice)` you will need to use do try catch syntax